How do you select fields from all structs in a list in Polars?
I'm working with a deeply nested DataFrame (not good practice, I know), and I'd like to express something like "select field X for all structs in list Y".
An example of the data structure:
import polars as pl

data = {
    "a": [
        [{
            "x": [1, 2, 3],
            "y": [4, 5, 6]
        },
        {
            "x": [2, 3, 4],
            "y": [3, 4, 5]
        }
        ]
    ],
}
df = pl.DataFrame(data)

In this case, I'd like to select field "x" in both of the structs, and gather them into a df with two series, call them"x_1" and "x_2".
In other words, the desired output is:
┌───────────┬───────────┐
│ x_1       ┆ x_2       │
│ ---       ┆ ---       │
│ list[i64] ┆ list[i64] │
╞═══════════╪═══════════╡
│ [1, 2, 3] ┆ [2, 3, 4] │
└───────────┴───────────┘

I don't know the length of the list ahead of time, and I'd like to do this dynamically (i.e. without hard-coding the field names). I'm not sure whether this is possible using Polars expressions?
Thanks in advance!

Can you show the expected output in DataFrame form? The description is a bit ambiguous.

Good suggestion @jqurious. Added now

Update: Perhaps a simpler approach using .unstack()
(df.select(pl.col("a").flatten().struct.field("x"))
   .unstack(1)
)

shape: (1, 2)
┌───────────┬───────────┐
│ x_0       ┆ x_1       │
│ ---       ┆ ---       │
│ list[i64] ┆ list[i64] │
╞═══════════╪═══════════╡
│ [1, 2, 3] ┆ [2, 3, 4] │
└───────────┴───────────┘


Original answer:
df.select(
   pl.col("a").list.eval(pl.element().struct["x"])
     .list.to_struct("max_width", lambda idx: f"x_{idx + 1}")
).unnest("a")

shape: (1, 2)
┌───────────┬───────────┐
│ x_1       ┆ x_2       │
│ ---       ┆ ---       │
│ list[i64] ┆ list[i64] │
╞═══════════╪═══════════╡
│ [1, 2, 3] ┆ [2, 3, 4] │
└───────────┴───────────┘

Explanation

.list.eval() to loop through each list element, we extract each struct field.

df.select(
   pl.col("a").list.eval(pl.element().struct["x"])
)

# shape: (1, 1)
# ┌────────────────────────┐
# │ a                      │
# │ ---                    │
# │ list[list[i64]]        │
# ╞════════════════════════╡
# │ [[1, 2, 3], [2, 3, 4]] │
# └────────────────────────┘


.list.to_struct() to convert to a struct which will allow us to turn each inner list into its own column.

df.select(
   pl.col("a").list.eval(pl.element().struct["x"])
     .list.to_struct("max_width", lambda idx: f"x_{idx + 1}")
)

# shape: (1, 1)
# ┌───────────────────────┐
# │ a                     │
# │ ---                   │
# │ struct[2]             │
# ╞═══════════════════════╡
# │ {[1, 2, 3],[2, 3, 4]} │
# └───────────────────────┘


.unnest() the struct to create individual columns.


Polars-idiomatic and easy to understand. Thanks for your answer, I appreciate it!
